# How to modify Content-Disposition Header when using .net WebClient FileUpload

Tags: .net, file-upload, upload, header, webclient

Is it possible to manually set the `name` attribute in the multipart header when using .net WebClient UploadFile? Or is there another way to get this solved?

```
-----------------------8cda1896efcd67f
Content-Disposition: form-data; **name="file"**; filename="Testfile.txt"
Content-Type: application/octet-stream

This is a Testfile.
-----------------------8cda1896efcd67f--
```

Thanks for any suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the MultipartFormDataContent in the following way:

```
MultipartFormDataContent form = new MultipartFormDataContent();
string filename = @"Dir:\Testfile.txt"       
    , name = "file";
byte[] bytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(filename);

form.Add(new StringContent(name), "file");
form.Add(new ByteArrayContent(bytes), "File", Path.GetFileName(filename));
```